# Find files in folders and subfolders that were created on the current date

Tags: php, spl

I am trying to find files that were created today. I found most of my answer in other posts, but can't quite get it right. The code below echos all of the files instead of just those that were created today. Any suggestions? Thanks.

```
$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/documents/listings');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) 
{

    if (date ("m-d-Y", filemtime($file)) == date("m-d-Y")) 

    { echo $filename . '<br/>'; }

}
```

Comment: works for me. prints out all files created today and the directories created all time.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now. Dug down the output and saw two files created today. 

There are hundreds of files in the directories and I assumed that when it showed all of the folder names it was not filtering by date.

How can I get the folder name that the matching file was found in?
Thanks!

Comment: the file name will return full path with folder name .

Comment: @ris    

My ultimate goal is to use the above script to check (daily) what new files have been uploaded to my server. Then upload the matching folders and files to an S3 bucket using:  

     $client->uploadDirectory($filename, 'my_bucket');

However, I don't need the file name, just the path/foldername that the matching file(s) reside in.
 
Example... $filename outputs:
../deals/upload/documents/lists/0000Main_Street15/a_file.pdf

But I only need:
../deals/upload/documents/lists/0000Main_Street15/

How can I get just the path without the filename?

Thanks.

Comment: @doev

"works for me. prints out all files created today and the directories created all time."

How do I make it show ONLY the files/paths created today, but NOT the directories created all time?

Comment: @user2413654 use dirname($filepath); it will give you the parent folder path

Comment: Notice: Most UNIX-like filesystems do not record a file's creation time.

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, about function [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php), it returns: file modification time.

But also exists function [filectime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php), it returns: inode change time of file.

As i found **filectime** more better for your question, but it really returns files not only created today but also edited today.

My code:

```
<?php

$path = dirname(__FILE__);

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach ($objects as $file => $object) {
    $basename = basename($file);
    if ($basename == '.' or $basename == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    if (is_dir($file)) {
        continue;
    }
    if (date('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d', filectime($file))) {
        echo $file . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works best so far to accomplish what I need. It outputs just the files. I then run:

    $client->uploadDirectory($file, 'my.bucket');

After running, I noticed it might be better for me to check the directory modification time instead of the file, in case there are multiple files that match the current date, otherwise it is uploading the whole directory each time a file date match is found. How would I check the directory modification date instead?

Answer (score 1):

your code is working for me . please check the file create date once.or try with change of directory you created in past

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!is_dir($file) && date ("m-d-Y", filemtime($file)) == date("m-d-Y"))
```

Maybe you only want to display the files without the directories? Try this for condition.